# Why Does jQuery's serializeArray take parameters in rails when its docs show none?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I was reading [DHH's post on getting jQuery going with Rails.](http://www.loudthinking.com/posts/32-myth-3-rails-forces-you-to-use-prototype)

What do the second (null) and third ('script') parameters do in this code example:

```
$(this).serializeArray(), null, 'script');
```

It has parameters. I went to the [jQuery serializeArray doc page](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/). It lists no parameters. Is it a rails thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those parameters are for `$.post` ajax call, not `serializeArray`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#new_comment").submit(function() {
    $.post($(this).attr('action') + '.js', 
      $(this).serializeArray(), null, 'script');
    return false;
  });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/